# Javascript value to PHP with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm a beginner with PHP, Javascript, Jquery (mobile).
I made a slider in Jquery Mobile and want to output the value of the slider to a php page with Ajax. The PHP page then writes the value to a .txt file. If I execute the slider without the Ajax command, but with an alert (value) then the value is printed, so this works like it should.

But the value never reaches the .txt file, so there must be something wrong in here. This is my html/javascript code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#tempslider").on("slidestop", function () {
          var graden = $(this).val();
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'text.php',
              data: 'graden',
              success: function (output) {
                  alert(output);
              }
          });
      });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body
<div data-role="page" id="thermostaat">
  <div data-role=header data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Terug">
    <h1>Thermostaat</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form>
      <label for="tempslider">Temperatuur instellen op:</label>
      <input type="range" name="tempslider" id="tempslider" min="15" max="24" value="<?php $onoff = file_get_contents('/var/www/thermostaat.txt'); echo $onoff; ?>" data-show-value="true" data-popup-enabled="true" step="0.5" data-highlight="true">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

And this is my php code

```
<?php
  $myFile = "thermostaat.txt";
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
  $stringData = $_POST['graden'];
  fwrite($fh, $stringData);
  fclose($fh);
?>
```

Like you see, I want to pass the value of "graden".

If I look in my Apache logs then I see this:

```
[error] [client 192.168.1.6] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: graden in /var/www/text.php on line 4, referer: http://192.168.1.202/switch.php
```

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove ' ' quotes in  `data: graden,`

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#tempslider").on("slidestop", function () {
          var graden = $(this).val();
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'text.php',
              data: {
                  'graden': graden
              }, //send data object to the php
              success: function (output) {
                  alert(output);
              }
          });
      });
  });
</script>
```

Solution for your `PHP Notice:  Undefined index:` error

use [`isset();`](http://www.php.net/isset%E2%80%8E)

```
if(isset($_POST['graden'])){

  $stringData = $_POST['graden'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Quotes should be removed from `data:'garden'`

Because , If you pass it in string,then jQuery passes it as A simple WORD as parameter and in PHP file you want Actual data, but if you don't use Quotes, jQuery considers it as var garden VARIABLE that you created.